# Excluding certain files and directories when deleting files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rm

My top-level directory is `data`. `data` includes several directories and these directories have sub-directories. I need to remove all files and directories inside `data/` except several files in some directories.

For example, data includes the directories `100` and `101`. I just want to keep `a.txt` and `b.txt` files in `100/` and `c.txt` and `d.txt` files in `101/` while removing all other files and directories in `100` and `101`.

Example:

```
.
├── 100
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   ├── c.txt
│   └── d.txt
└── 101
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    ├── c.txt
    └── d.txt
```

I use `rm -rf !(a.txt|b.txt)` command but I can't apply this command for each directory automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you already found out you can use the `extglob` feature which is enabled with:

```bsh
shopt -s extglob
```

This allows to exclude matches so that you can do things like:

```bsh
rm 100/!([ab].txt) 101/!([cd].txt)
```

It's a good idea to test it with `echo` first. This example will match anything inside `100/` which is not `a.txt` or `b.txt` and anything inside `101/` which is not `c.txt` or `d.txt`. If the same rules for `100/` apply to `102/` as well you can do e.g.:

```bsh
10[02]/!([ab].txt) # or
{100,102}/!([ab].txt)
```

Comment: I just gave an example for 100 and 101 directories but in reality the number of sub-directories are nearly 20. Is there a way to implement above code for each directory without writing each directory name in the main folder?

Comment: @deepblue Please provide an exact example for that in your question ([edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/991501/edit)), it's especially unclear how `rm` should know which files to keep in which directories if you don't want to specify that.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `find` for this. You can negate tests in `find` with `-not` or `!`. This will exclude matches, rather than finding them.

You should be careful not to delete any of the parent directories of the files you want to keep, **especially the current directory** `.`, so make sure you read the output thoroughly before deleting.

Based on your example you could do something like this from the `data` directory.

```
find ! -path . ! -path ./100 ! -path ./101 ! -path "./100/[ab].txt" ! -path "./101/[cd].txt"
```

Add a `! -path ./path/to/dir` for any path you want to avoid deleting. You can use metacharacters like `*`, but make sure you quote the expression if you do, eg `"./path*dir"`, to prevent any unwanted expansions.

`find` is recursive by default. Even if we don't find `./100` here, we will find all of its contents unless they match the pattern `[ab].txt`. If you can't match all the names you want to keep, add another test:

```
! -path "./100/[ab].txt" ! -path ./100/foo
```

This won't find `a.txt` or `b.txt` or `foo`, but it will find all other files.

When you are sure you see what you want, you can add `-delete` to the end to delete the found files:

```
find ! -path . ! -path ./100 ! -path ./101 ! -path "./100/[ab].txt" ! -path "./101/[cd].txt" -delete
```